# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for physics research
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/6388).

Answer (score 36):

[image: arXiv.org -- open access to over 800 000 e-prints]

Comment: copied from the [2014 ad thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5266/124)

Answer (score 35):

[image: Detexify2 - LaTeX symbol classifier]

Comment: copied from the [2014 ad thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5271/124)

Answer (score 19):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Comment: From the [2013 thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/2814/25301)

Answer (score 15):

[Current Physics Stack Exchange bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/physics.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://physics.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: copied from the [2014 ad thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5296/124)

Answer (score 14):

[image: Space Exploration Stack Exchange]

Comment: From the [2014 thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5268/21740)

Answer (score 14):

[image: HSM]

Comment: Maybe a miniaturic section from an antic, yellow paper with newtons handscripts of his first integral symbols?

Comment: @peterh you mean something like [this](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71ef4-zmjvL.jpg)?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Exactly!

Comment: Image has been updated for the original version.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Engineering Stack Exchange]

Comment: [Thread at Meta.Engineering.SE](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/174/community-ads-to-use-in-other-sites), hopefully they'll come up with something prettier.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Haikus are awesome/ Chemistry is more so/ Ask straight away!]

Comment: I feel tempted to downvote this because I'm jealous of what the SE designers have done for the Chemistry site. :( (I like our Mexican Hat though, but this is so _chic_!)

Comment: The white label is **ugly**.

Comment: Manish, can you comment on where this image came from? How hard will it be to update to 300x250 for the 2016 thread?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/2720/22

Answer (score 12):

[image: PhysicsOverflow: a graduate-level upward physics site]

Comment: Please avoid discussion and comments here. Use instead the [related meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6196/2451) and [its chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17799).

Answer (score 11):

[image: The Fun Physics]

Comment: Copied from the [2014 ad thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5263/community-promotion-ads-2014/6211#6211)

Answer (score 10):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: This is displaying "Tagline to show on mouseover". Can you fix that please: perhaps explain what this is advertising?

Comment: @ChrisW: Point 1 in the OP says I cannot (it must be in the exact form as the template). I thought it was clear what it was advertising, but it's a script that allows you to have MathJax (Latex) hotkeys in the normal site edit box.

Comment: Same 'form' as the template but different 'content': look at http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/posts/6407/edit for example, all the other advertisements contain informative mouse-over text. When I saw this advertisement, I couldn't discover what it was advertising.

Comment: @ChrisW: Meh. Anyway, that mouse over text produces the same thing as what's on the body of the image so it seems extremely superfluous. Considering the image here explains precisely what it is, I'm not sure what problems you've run into.

Comment: You say that this "physics editor" is a script: but, for example, I don't know where to get this script from.

Comment: @ChrisW: You do realize that every single one of these ads on this site is a *hyperlink* to the thing they promote? So have you bothered to actually click the link?

Answer (score 10):

[image: Astronomy Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 9):

[image: arXiv Analytics: specialized web portal dedicated to reading & discussing arXiv eprints]

Answer (score 9):

[image: If you want down-to-earth answers to your questions]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Physics Forums]

Comment: copied from the [2014 ad thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/6332/124)

Answer (score 7):

[image: SciRate]

Comment: From the previous year: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5982/184

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: New site for researches interested in structure determination]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: This is maybe not quite an awesome fit for this site, but I thought I'd float the idea here.

Answer (score 2):

[image: What if? Serious scientific answers to absurd hypothetical questions]

Comment: I'm proposing this for Physics.SE, building on the fact that the [same proposal in Academia.SE](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1485/17534) turned out to be quite popular, and I would expect some kind of parity between the _xkcd-fetish_ in both communities.

Comment: On the other hand, what-if has mostly stopped regular updates.

Comment: Sad. 11 characters.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answer (score -3):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score -4):

[image: Worldbuilding Workshop - building worlds so you don't have to]

Comment: Made to promote the Worldbuilding SE Worldbuilding Workshop project.

Comment: The font is very hard to read.

Answer (score -5):

[image: Physics homework questions Q&A]

Comment: Why downvote? Site proposal ads are not permitted?

Comment: I would read downvotes on this as disagreement with the proposal or with that proposal as something we should advertise. Site proposal ads are perfectly allowed and (some) have been well received in the past - see the threads from previous years to get a feel for how the community tends to feel about these.

Answer (score -6):

[image: Competitive Exams]

Comment: Why downvote? Site proposal ads are not permitted?