# How can I view the breakdown of votes on an answer versus the simple total?

Tags: feature-request

I recently had a non-multiple of 5 rep points for an answer (specifically, 18).  I assume that is due to 2 positive votes and one negative, but there was no comment explaining the down vote.

When I look back at the answer, I see it has a total of +1, but there doesn't seem to be a way to view the individual votes.  Is there a way to view them?  I don't know that it would serve any important purpose other than to satisfy curiosity.

Comment: Click on the number of votes itself, should show you the up and down votes.

Comment: Also, comments with regards to votes are not mandatory, so you shouldn't expect any comments explaining the downvote.

Comment: Ah! Thanks @KyleKanos. I know about the comments issue. Has there been a discussion of forcing a comment on downvotes but providing a checkbox to allow for possible anonymity? Would it be worthwhile to ask about adding that feature?

Comment: Maybe not on this meta site, but Meta.stackexchange.com probably has one or two on that.

Comment: Forced comment suggestions in many, *many* variants have been uniformly and firmly shot down on the mother meta. Everyone gets an annoying drive-by down votes from time to time, but they are here to stay.

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible with the [**Established User**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege at 1,000 rep. Click on the post's score and you'll see the upvote/downvote breakdown. On occasion, this can be quite useful - particularly on meta for things like polls. (As an extreme example, [this answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6399/), currently at +24-21.)

For <1k rep users, you can find out the vote counts on your own posts via [the reputation tab of your profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation&sort=post), which will show the net upvotes and downvotes for each post, per day.